# Is it possible to make Slack notify me only when my own personal @name is mentioned?

Tags: notifications, slack

I'd like notifications on one of our Slack channels only when my own `@user.name` is mentioned in the channel.

What happens now is that I get a notification whenever ANY `@mention` is used in the channel.

What I did so far to try to resolve this:

1. I've read through https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201355156-Guide-to-desktop-notifications
2. Made sure that "Notify me about..." is set to "Direct messages, mentions & keywords" is set in the Notifications preferences.
3. Made sure I don't have any extra keyword defined for my user and still couldn't find why I get notifications when I'm not mentioned.
4. Made sure that the channel's specific notification preferences are set to "Just mentions", which is defined as "Includes mentions of your name or any of your keywords".

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Questions about how to use Slack are better asked here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slack

Comment: Thanks. I copied the question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/is-it-possible-to-make-slack-notify-me-only-when-my-own-persona-name-is-mention